# Adding "expires" directive in Nginx conf for assets causes "404 not found" errors

Tags: performance, page-speed, nginx, django

I have a live Django site running gunicorn, nginx, supervisord. I am trying to implement the suggestions found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-increase-pagespeed-score-by-changing-your-nginx-configuration-on-ubuntu-16-04) to increase my page speed score by using gzip in nginx. The resulting config file is as follows:

```
upstream app_server_wsgiapp {
   server 127.0.0.1:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
   listen 80;
   server_name www.example.com;
   return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    server_name           www.example.com;
    listen                443 ssl;

    if ($host = 'example.com') {
      return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
    }

    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/example/example.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/example/example.key;
    ssl_session_timeout   1d;
    ssl_session_cache     shared:SSL:50m;
    ssl_protocols         TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers           'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA';
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
    access_log            /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.access.log;
    error_log             /var/log/nginx/www.example.com.error.log info;
    keepalive_timeout     5;
    proxy_read_timeout    120s;

    # nginx serve up static and media files and never send to the WSGI server
    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /path/to/static/files;
    }

    location /media {
        autoindex on;
        alias /path/to/media/files;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://app_server_wsgiapp;
            break;
        }
    }

    gzip on;
    gzip_comp_level    5;
    gzip_min_length    256;
    gzip_proxied       any;
    gzip_vary          on;

    gzip_types
    application/atom+xml
    application/javascript
    application/json
    application/ld+json
    application/manifest+json
    application/rss+xml
    application/vnd.geo+json
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject
    application/x-font-ttf
    application/x-web-app-manifest+json
    application/xhtml+xml
    application/xml
    font/opentype
    image/bmp
    image/svg+xml
    image/x-icon
    text/cache-manifest
    text/css
    text/plain
    text/vcard
    text/vnd.rim.location.xloc
    text/vtt
    text/x-component
    text/x-cross-domain-policy;

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
        expires 7d;
    }
}
```

After restarting nginx and opening my site in a browser, everything appears to be fine. I then check the [page speed here](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) and my score has indeed increased.

The problem is that if I go back to my site and press `Ctrl+F5` for a full refresh of the page and re-download the static files (just to really make sure everything is working correctly), the static files do not download. I get the following browser console errors:

```
GET https://www.example.com/path/to/static/files 404 (Not Found)
etc...
etc...
```

None of the static files are found or downloaded. If I edit the nginx config file and comment out the last 3 lines and restart nginx then it works (even when pressing `CTRL+F5`), ie:

```
# location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)$ {
#     expires 7d;
# }
```

So it seems as though the issue is something related to those 3 lines. However with those 3 lines commented out, I do not get any page speed increase which defeats the point of trying to use gzip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`location` blocks are not additive. `nginx` selects a `location` block to process a request. By adding a new `location` block, you prevent your existing `location` blocks from processing the request. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.

As you have multiple `location` blocks with multiple `alias` directives, it may be simpler to use a global `expires` directive to be inherited by your existing `location` blocks.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $expires {
    default off;
    ~*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|pdf)(\?|$) 7d;
}
server {
    ...
    expires $expires;
    ...
    location ... {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires) for more.